# text inside input select not in the middle

Tags: html, css

hi i am trying to use a input select with a height 36px ,

```
    <select name="qui" id="choose" style="position:absolute;top:202px;left:14px;
    width:418px;height:36px;font:  1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#b3b3b3;
    padding-left:30px;">
    <option value='' disabled selected >Êtes vous ?</option> 
    <option value='Particulier' >Particulier</option> 
    <option value='Professionel' >Professionel</option> 
    </select>
```

what i expect to hava is something like that [image]

but the problem when i open it with mozila in another computer i get this

[image]

this text is higher than i expect to be , what can i do

Answer (score 0):

Try this `padding:.3em;/.4em;` to the select box.

http://jsfiddle.net/DaSa7/3/

Answer (score 0):

Your best option may be to just manually adjust the top padding:

```
padding-top:5px;
```

**Note:**

- Padding will depend on your font size.
- Use padding in `px`, if your font size is in `px`.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LzZxr/1/)**